# knockout with MVC4 how to bind a property of an object to a list with values

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am at the first MVC4 app using knockout. I have a list of books and every book has a category ('domeniu'). I need at insert or update to have a dropdownlist with all the categories.

Books and categories are in a SQL database (using EF code first). I've managed to view a list of all the books, to edit and insert except this property. The last try was to add a property to my book object and populate it with a JSON object with all categories.
It's something like:
Code from view model class

this.titlul = ko.observable("@Model.Carte.Titlul");
......
this.domeniuId = ko.observable("@Model.Carte.DomeniuID");
this.domenii = ko.observable(JSON.stringify(@Html.Raw(Model.DomeniiJSON)));

And the result in debugger for this.domenii

[{"domeniuId":1,"domeniul":"Engleza"},{"domeniuId":2,"domeniul":"Romana"},{"domeniuId":3,"domeniul":"Matematica"},{"domeniuId":4,"domeniul":"Geografie"},{"domeniuId":5,"domeniul":"Istorie"}]

In books I have the `domeniuId` property so I need to show `domeniul` property from the categories and put `domeniulId` in books.
But this code does not show anything:

```
<select id="domeniuId" name="domeniuId" data-bind="options: model.domenii, optionsText: 'domeniul', optionsValue: 'domeniuId', value: model.domeniuId, optionsCaption: 'Alege domeniul...'" />
```

Where I can find a sample or something about this problem ?

**[update]**

Some of my code from my class which will become the view model

```
this.titlul = ko.observable("@Model.Carte.Titlul"); 
this.domeniuId = ko.observable("@Model.Carte.DomeniuID"); 
this.domenii = ko.observable(JSON.stringify(@Html.Raw(Model.DomeniiJSON)));
```

And the result of `domenii` in debugger:

```
[{\"domeniuId\":1,\"domeniul\":\"Engleza\"},{\"domeniuId\":2,\"domeniul\":\"Roma‌​na\"},{\"domeniuId\":3,\"domeniul\":\"Matematica\"}]
```

Comment: Could you post your current model definition?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select
id="domeniuId"
name="domeniuId"
data-bind=" options: model.domenii,
            optionsText: 'domeniul',
            optionsValue: 'domeniuId',
            value: 'domeniuId',
            optionsCaption: 'Alege domeniul...'" />
```

The JS:

```
var model = {
    domenii: json
};

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

See it working on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jt4yz/1/).

Comment: Hi My model is of type Book not Category. I think this is where I am confused. I've tried to add a property to my model and in that prop I've put categories (model.domenii)

Comment: Some of my code
from my class which will become viewmodel
<!-- language: lang-js -->
this.titlul = ko.observable("@Model.Carte.Titlul");
......
this.domeniuId = ko.observable("@Model.Carte.DomeniuID");
this.domenii = ko.observable(JSON.stringify(@Html.Raw(Model.DomeniiJSON)));
<!-- language: lang-none -->
And the result of domenii in debugger
<!-- language: lang-js -->
[{\"domeniuId\":1,\"domeniul\":\"Engleza\"},{\"domeniuId\":2,\"domeniul\":\"Romana\"},{\"domeniuId\":3,\"domeniul\":\"Matematica\"}]
<!-- language: lang-none -->

Comment: Just add the code to the original question's body (also, by doing that, everyone looking at the question will have some more info about the issue).

Comment: H
It's all about formatting that result
I have escaped '"' with '\"' and that's the cause it's not working.
How can I do ?